# Which platform should be installed to use Firebase Storage in Flutter Desktop?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I'm building a desktop application with Flutter. Operating system Windows. I will do operations with Firebase Storage in this program. But I don't know which platform to install.

Which one should I continue with?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

For the moment you'll have to create an `iOS+` app descriptor in Firebase for your Mac application, with the little `+` after iOS indicating "other Apple platforms". We're working on making this more obvious.

**Update**: Oops, I see I misread your target platform. Windows is currently not a supported platform for the Firebase plugins for Flutter. See the [supported platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#available-plugins) in the Firebase documentation for Flutter.

Comment: I will make the desktop program for Windows. Which one should I choose for this? I didn't ask for macOS.

Comment: Check my update @EmirBolat